# IOS не работает анимация svg

Tags: ios, svg, анимация

Ссылка на пример, в хроме при нажатии кружок заполняется, в ios заполнения не происходит.
В чем проблема кто может подсказать?

```js
var $slider = $('.slider');

if ($slider.length) {
  var currentSlide;
  var slidesCount;
  var sliderCounter = document.createElement('div');
  sliderCounter.classList.add('slider__counter');
  
  var updateSliderCounter = function(slick, currentIndex) {
    currentSlide = slick.slickCurrentSlide() + 1;
    slidesCount = slick.slideCount;
    $(sliderCounter).text(currentSlide + '/' +slidesCount)
  };

  $slider.on('init', function(event, slick) {
    $slider.append(sliderCounter);
    updateSliderCounter(slick);
  });

  $slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    updateSliderCounter(slick, currentSlide);
  });

  $slider.slick();
}


/*SVG*/
 var circle = document.querySelector('.progress-line');
    var btnPrev = document.querySelector('.slick-prev');
    var btnNext = document.querySelector('.slick-next');
    function setCircle(){
        if(circle.style.strokeDashoffset == '1000') {
            return;
        }
        var offset = +(circle.style.strokeDashoffset) + 100;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
    }
    btnNext.addEventListener('click', setCircle);

    function setCircleRev(){
        if(circle.style.strokeDashoffset == '600') {
            return;
        }
        var offset = +(circle.style.strokeDashoffset) - 100;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
    }
    btnPrev.addEventListener('click', setCircleRev);
```

```css
.question__svg-round {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-455deg);
    transform: rotate(-455deg);
}
.slider {
  .slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.25s;

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      border-color: #f08a5d;
    }

    &:active {
      transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
    }
  }

  .slick-prev {
    left: 10vw;
  }

  .slick-next {
    right: 10vw;
  }
}

.slider__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 20vh;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

.slider__counter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" class="question__svg-round" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
                        <defs><filter id="blurFilter" y="-5" height="40"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" y="3"/></filter></defs>
                        <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="#666" filter="url(#blurFilter)"></circle>
                        <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="#ccc" stroke-dasharray="502,4 502,4" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
                        <circle class="progress-line" style="stroke-dashoffset: 600;" r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-width="12" stroke="#37A58C" stroke-dasharray="502" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
                    </svg> 
<div class="slider op">
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471110338536-858caa3dbe45?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497042293529-97936e977f99?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503264116251-35a269479413?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478281437946-5179e2443a10?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen.io/pavel-s/pen/ZEpWMGQ

Answer (score 0):

Одной из возможных причин отказа работы  в `IOS` `safari` являются отрицательные значения `stroke-dashoffset`

Например в вопросе на enSO задавался подобный вопрос [Animated stroke-dashoffset on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964904/7394871) [@Axiol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195999/axiol)

Смысл был в следующем, почему при отрицательных значения `stroke-dashoffset` везде работает, кроме iOS Safari

```
@keyframes firstLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: -496; }
  40% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  85% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
}
```

Решение было найдено,- **использовать положительное, но удвоенное значение**  `stroke-dashoffset :992;`

ответ:

```css
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
}
.cls-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 496;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: firstLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

.cls-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 458;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: secondLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes firstLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
  40% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  85% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
}

@keyframes secondLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 458; }
  45% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  90% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200.17 135">
<path class="cls-1 " d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27" >
</path>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27" > 
</path>
 
</svg>
```

**На будущее**, safari не признает `href` в SVG коде, легально до выхода стандарта SVG2 только `xlink:href=""`

<sub>[ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243056/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt). (Требования лицензии при ссылке на EnSO. Хотя это и мой ответ, но  ответ, который находится на другом сайте)</sub>

Comment: с этим все впорядке